# Multiple Turtlebots in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, ros-electric, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to separate the /cmd_vel and /odom topics when spawning multiple turtlebots in Gazebo?

My launch file looks like this:

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" /> 
 <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/simple_office.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
   
<group ns="robot1">
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'" /> 
  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model1" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args=" -urdf -param robot_description -namespace robo1 -x 0 -y 1  -model robo1" respawn="false" output="screen"/>   

</group>

<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'" /> 
 <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model2" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args=" -urdf -param robot_description -namespace robo2 -x 1 -y 1  -model robo2" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model3" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args=" -urdf -param robot_description -namespace robo3 -x 1 -y -1   -model robo3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

and rostopic list looks like this:

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/depth/points
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/clock
/cmd_vel
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/paused
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/joint_states
/odom
/robo1/depth/camera_info
/robo1/depth/image_raw
/robo1/imu/data
/robo1/scan
/robo1/set_hfov
/robo1/set_update_rate
/robo2/depth/camera_info
/robo2/depth/image_raw
/robo2/imu/data
/robo2/scan
/robo2/set_hfov
/robo2/set_update_rate
/robo3/depth/camera_info
/robo3/depth/image_raw
/robo3/imu/data
/robo3/scan
/robo3/set_hfov
/robo3/set_update_rate
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state
```

With this setup I see 3 turtlebots in gazebo but get only one cmd_vel and odom topic so I can't control only them separately.
I use natty with electric

Any ideas? Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33981/multiple-turtlebots-in-gazebo/) by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-14**:
What nodes are generating your odom and cmd_vel messages?

**Comment by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) on 2012-05-14**:
Thanks Ryan, I tried your solution and changed line 36 to
node_namespaceP_ = new ParamTstd::string("robotNamespace","",0);
but the topics still are /odom and /cmd_vel. What else needs to be changed?

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-15**:
Did you test to see that passing in that renamed parameter via the URDF (gazebo.urdf.xacro) in turtlebot_description renames it correctly?

**Comment by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) on 2012-05-15**:
How do I do that? I'm not sure for what I have to look.

**Comment by [jjamp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2378/jjamp/) on 2012-05-16**:
and when will you release the new version of the turtlebot simulator?

**Comment by [maurizio](https://answers.ros.org/users/2958/maurizio/) on 2012-08-14**:
I actually tried to put in the xml file the robotNamespace parameter, but it is not detected... always cmd_vel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On line #36 in gazebo_ros_create.cpp in the turtlebot_gazebo_plugins package, change "node_namespace" to "robotNamespace". IIRC (I can't find the thread I used originally), the robotNamespace parameter is automatically populated with the Gazebo -namespace argument, and that'll turn into a prefix to odom and cmd_vel.

I think that's all I had to do to fix this particular problem - we have an as-yet-unreleased branch of the TurtleBot simulator code which has been fully tested with this, but we have just been a little too busy to put together the patches.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am also working with 2 Turtlebots in Gazebo (ROS Fuerte). I was able to separate both `/cmd_vel` and `/odom` topics. Here is what I did:

Go to gazebo_ros_create.h and add a new private variable:

```
std::string robot_namespace_;
```

Go to gazebo_ros_create.cpp. Add the following lines in the function `GazeboRosCreate::Load` (I added it around line 56)

```
this->robot_namespace_ = "";
if (_sdf->HasElement("robotNamespace")) { 
  this->robot_namespace_ = _sdf->GetElement("robotNamespace")->GetValueString() + "/";
}
```

With that line you are getting the namespace you assigned for the nodes (in my case turtle_1 and turtle_2). Modify the line corresponding to `node_namespace` in order to add the `robotNamespace` String on it:

```
this->node_namespace_ = "";
if (_sdf->HasElement("node_namespace")) {
  this->node_namespace_ = this->robot_namespace_ + _sdf->GetElement("node_namespace")->GetValueString() + "/";
}
```

Now go down and find the lines in which you subscribe/advertise the topics `/cmd_vel`, `/odom` and `/sensor_state` and change them to local names `cmd_vel`, `odom` and `sensor_state`. The lines should now look like this:

```
cmd_vel_sub_ = rosnode_->subscribe("cmd_vel", 1, &GazeboRosCreate::OnCmdVel, this );

sensor_state_pub_ = rosnode_->advertise<turtlebot_node::TurtlebotSensorState>("sensor_state", 1);
odom_pub_ = rosnode_->advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 1);
joint_state_pub_ = rosnode_->advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states", 1);
```

Finally, `rosmake` the package (make sure that you generate a new library, erase the ROS_NOBUILD if needed (otherwise the library won't be compiled and your changes won't be effective)

Hope it helps. If you found other way to work around this (other than editing the source code), please let me know.

Thanks!

Ana

---

Originally posted by [Ana](https://answers.ros.org/users/3666/ana/) with karma: 41 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1